# Problems running Quarkus sample application from a GraalVM image-based Docker container

Tags: docker, quarkus, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, quarkus-native

Working on **Windows 10**, I downloaded the simple **Quarkus** sample prototype.

I run it normally and be able to access **http://localhost:8118/hello**, except if I try to run it from the **native image executable** for **GraalVM**.

I have to say that I don't have GraalVM installed, but I'm trying to do it from a **Docker** container (called *contenedor-graalvm-1*) based on the following GraalVM image:
*container-registry.oracle.com/graalvm/community:ol8-java17-22.3.0-b1*

The sequence I follow is:

```
docker start contenedor-graalvm-1

docker exec -it contenedor-graalvm-1 bash

cd code-with-quarkus-one/target
```

And then, successive launch attempts:

```
A)
./code-with-quarkus-one-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner -Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0 -Dquarkus.http.port=8118

B)
./code-with-quarkus-one-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner -Dquarkus.http.host=192.168.49.147 -Dquarkus.http.port=8118

C)
./code-with-quarkus-one-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner -Dquarkus.http.host=127.0.0.1 -Dquarkus.http.port=8118

D)
./code-with-quarkus-one-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner -Dquarkus.http.host=localhost -Dquarkus.http.port=8118
```

That seems to start properly (except -B- option):

[image]

But none of them allow me to access to the desired endpoint:

[image]

Any help will be appreciatted.

Comment: Have you tried using `quarkus-container-image-docker` or `quarkus-container-image-jib` that give Quarkus the ability to create the container for you? See https://quarkus.io/guides/container-image

Comment: If you check the text in the screenshot all containers write that they were stopped in less than a second, so they are not running when you call them. Try to find out why they are stopping.